# Creating domain objects when testing a grails service

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I am trying to create unit tests for testing my grails services.  I have the following test

```
@TestFor(ActivityProcessorService)

@Mock([ActivityProcessorService, Activity])
class ActivityProcessorServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase{
void setUp() {

}

void tearDown() {
    // Tear down logic here
}

void testGenerateDescription() {

    def activity = new Activity(
        //new activity details
        )

   def service = mockFor(ActivityProcessorService)
   def description = service.generateDescription(activity)

   assert description == "something..."
 }
}
```

My problem is when creating an `Activity` object and populating all the required fields, it requires me to create several other objects, such as `User`, `Task` and some others, where these objects can be quite large, which has a knock on effect that they require the creation of objects etc.

Is there a way that I can create an `Activity` object but omit the creation of fully populated objects such as `Task`, `User` and other large objects?

E.g

```
def activity = new Activity(
        task: new Task(),
        user: new User(),
        ... and so on
        )
```

where Task and User are mocked up rather than creating full objects such as

```
def activity = new Activity(
        task: new Task(
                title : "task title"
                description : "task description"
                ... and so on
            ),
        user: new User(
                firstName : "john",
                lastName : "smith",
                ... and so on
            ),
        ... and so on
        )
```

as this will make a rather large overhead for creating such a small and simple test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this [release notes](http://grails.org/2.1.4+Release+Notes), you have to manually specify `Task` and `User` in `@Mock` or `@Build` (build-test-data-plugin: 2.0.5)

Comment: thanks, ill keep that in mind, but is there a way to mock up the likes of `Task` and `User` without having to populate all the fields of these objects, as they are quite large objects, seems overkill for such a small test

Comment: You can use [build-test-data](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) plugin to overcome this problem.

Comment: ah sorry didnt see that plugin in your first comment, thanks, that looks perfect!